# should 'do' be used in this type of interrogative sentence below?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, interrogatives, wh-questions

> Can you tell me how **do** you/people feel about...?

Should auxiliary "**do**" be used in the sentence ? if shouldn't, then why? is there any general distictive rule to determine it easily. For example, it may be that there's a rule preventing the use of two auxiliary verbs(**can** and **do**) in one interrogative sentence, and that's why we cannot use "**do**" or there's another thing related to it? Please if possible, explain it by providing examples that looks like the same question patterns. Thanks in advance for all for your time and help.

Comment: "Can you tell me (the answer to this): how do you feel about...?" That can be done if you separate the clauses.  If not, it's "Can you tell me how you feel about...?"

Answer (score 1):

In normal questions, the verb *do* is needed when there's no other auxiliary to perform the subject-auxiliary inversion. For example:

- **Does** he like me? (cf. *he likes me*.)

However, the subject-auxiliary inversion does not occur in subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions) and free relative clauses. In your sentence, the question *how you feel about [...]* is embedded in another sentence *can you tell me how [...]*.

> [Can you tell me [how you feel about...]] ?

So the subject-auxiliary inversion does not occur, hence, the absence of *do*.

Comment: That all said, the situation might be changed if we punctuate the sentence differently, i.e.: _Can you tell me: How do you feel about X?_

Comment: @J.R. That's true. But I'm not sure whether we can call that a subordinate clause.

Comment: Let's omit the first auxiliary , **can** - *please tell me how..you feel about x?*   do we now need to use *do* in this sententence?

Comment: @CavidHummatov by the same token, you don't need it.

Comment: *please* is not an auxillary verb, so why don't we need??

Comment: @CavidHummatov No, the presence or absence of auxiliary verb in the matrix clause doesn't make any difference. You just have to remember: auxiliary *do* or any kind of subject-auxiliary inversion is not needed in a question that's embedded in another sentence.

Comment: could you possibly mention briefly what *subject-auxiliary inversion* is exactly? I think I couldn't conceive that very well.

Comment: @CavidHummatov subject-auxiliary inversion (or subject-operator inversion in some grammars) is the process of inverting the subject and the first auxiliary verb in a question. For example: 1. *He is working* (no inversion); 2._**is he** working?_ (with subject-auxiliary inversion). When there's no other auxiliary verb, a verb *do* is used: 1. *You care about me* (no inversion); 2._**do** you care about me?_ (with subject-auxiliary inversion).

Comment: Now I've got the term - the case when auxilary precedes the verb to form question and hence, *inversion* :)  So the only thing we need to consider is whether the wh question is embeded in another sentence? right?

Comment: @CavidHummatov yup, exactly! :)

Comment: @user178049 Thanks for your patience and convincing answers :)